# What MVC frameworks are available for Java desktop/winform applications?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, user-interface

I am going to develop a winform application. I want to keep Model, View and Controller separate. I have not used any Java MVC frameworks, and have been out of touch with Java for a few years. Can anyone tell me some suitable frameworks, and their advantages and disadvantages, from their own experience?
I am planning to use the NetBeans IDE.

Comment: Java uses Swing, AWT and may be other frameworks. Do I Understand you right that you want to build desktop application? MVC is patern used more for web apps, im not aware that java would have any MVCs for desktop.

Comment: Yes I am going to develop a desktop app. And there must be something.

Comment: MVC can surely be used for any kind of application based on UI - being that web or desktop. In fact this architectural pattern precedes the web by at least 10 years... And please remember that Apple [uses it](http://www.cocoalab.com/?q=node/24) for developing desktop apps.

Comment: I understand your point, but actualy I think its a good thing that Swing doesnt make it a must to implement MVC. As @Mauricio suggested you could also try to use Netbeans platform(based on Swing). I stil dont think that Netbeans platform is the true MVC. And it wouldn't be my choice. I like more freedom to implement my frontend as I like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swing already supports some kind of MVC. It's only a UI toolkit however.
If you want more then look for a Rich Client Platform (highly recommended) such as the NetBeans Platform (Swing based) or Eclipse RCP (SWT based).

Comment: Thank for your answer. Eclipse RCP is great. I had no idea what you are talking about when you gave this answer. I realised much latter.

Answer (score 3):

[Griffon](http://griffon.codehaus.org/) is a nice framework that has an MVC structure and is made to develop desktop applications.

Answer (score 1):

checkout [Swing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html)

Comment: I dont think swing is something I am looking for.

Comment: so please be more specific in your question. Swing is more than just displaying cool components, is up to you using it's MVC features or not.

Answer (score 1):

Swing is your best choice, especialy with Netbeans(it has very nice gui editor for swing). And I guess that some components meet your MVC pattern read more in [this artilce](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-04-1998/jw-04-howto.html)