# Program Java Swing, Flex like

Tags: java, apache-flex, swing, user-interface

I've been programming in Flex for a while, and I'm used to the model of "variable binding" to update the interface.. this makes it really easy to decouple the logic from the gui, withouth thinking about events and handlers all the time..

In swing, is there a programming style that resembles that? Some framework, or simply a way of doing things that would be more familiar to my style of programming?
Thanks!

Comment: Try to read this discussion first http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4874625/what-are-mvc-frameworks-available-for-java-desktop-winform-application/4874784#4874784 it will give you some ideas on what is available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JGoodies](http://www.jgoodies.com/) does. JGoodies Bindings is dedicated to binding.

Swing and JGoodies is quite old now, and you can have a look on JavaFX if you want something more "shinny". But Swing + JGoodies will perfectly match your needs.

A JGoodies Binding tutorial : http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t17672

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to try JavaFX. It is declarative framework with data binding which utilizes Swing as widget framework.

Answer (score 0):

WindowBuilder Pro has this 'binding' functionality. (It's free now because of Google.) Although, still prefer Flex UIs. :)

http://code.google.com/javadevtools/wbpro/

But I can relate to your complaints - Swing/Java leaves a LOT to be desired once you've been exposed to the Flex SDK.  Flex and in some ways ActionScript itself are just much better suited to handling GUI challenges, making going back to Swing somewhat painful with all it's anon inner classes, dealing with the EDT, and verbose non-mxml layout bloat!